# I'm forced to redirect to logo page in Facebook App IFRAME

Tags: ruby, facebook, oauth, sinatra

I want to login to facebook in IFRAME(Facebook Apps).

Go http://apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/ with logoff and click "login" link.

Response header have Location Header when redirect permissions request dialog page.

Chrome screenshot below:

http://gyazo.com/0f4988158cb0e0a9f52545374540de96

If you have any ideas, let me know.

Source:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'oauth2'
require 'json'

@@client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com'
)

def redirect_uri
  uri = URI.parse(request.url)
  uri.path = '/auth/facebook/callback'
  uri.query = nil
  uri.to_s
end

get '/' do
  '<a href="/auth/facebook">login</a>'
end

post '/' do
  '<a href="/auth/facebook">login</a>'
end

get '/auth/facebook' do
  redirect @@client.web_server.authorize_url(
    :redirect_uri => redirect_uri,
    :scope => 'email,offline_access'
  )
end

get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
  access_token = @@client.web_server.get_access_token(
    params[:code],
    :redirect_uri => redirect_uri
  )
  user = JSON.parse(access_token.get('/me'))
  user.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of redirting user without permission you can easly 
solve it by adding target="_top" to link.

```
<a href="url" target="_top">login</a>
```

Comment: I want to login into IFRAME. Is this abnormal way for Facebook apps?

Comment: ok you can easly set it like apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/{controller}/{action} for example mine is apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/user/callback

Comment: I tried it(/auth/facebook/callback change to http://apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/auth/facebook/callback) but I have same result. (http://gyazo.com/e1a20e21fe0d40f3bf0c41b600cffb06)

Comment: apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/ in this page there is a login link change that link to   <a href="http://apps.facebook.com/oauthtwosample/auth/facebook/callback" target="_top">login</a> but the link must be working you can test it like localhost/auth/facebook/callback i tried but it gave me 404 error check your controller name and action name